# Concatenating a portion of each line of a file using BASH commands

Tags: bash, sed, append, concatenation, prepend

BASH version in use:

```
echo $BASH_VERSION
4.4.19(1)-release
```

I am using the following plumbing to extract all banned IP addresses from a fail2ban log file:

```
cat /var/www/html/fail2ban.log | grep Ban | cut -d "]" -f3 | cut -d "r" -f2 | cut -d "e" -f2 | cut -d " " -f3 | uq | sort -n > /var/www/html/fail2ban.html
```

This results in a HTML file with a list of IP addresses ordered from low to high.

My goal is to make each of the IP addresses clickable hyperlinks, for usability reasons.
I have been successful using the following operations:

---

**Step 1** - Prepend each line with the beginning portion of HTML hyperlinks.

Code used (successful): `sed -e 's/^/<a href=\"http:\/\//' -i /var/www/html/fail2ban.html`

**Step 2** - Append each line with the closing portion of HTML hyperlinks and a line break.

Code used (successful): `sed -e 's/$/\">CLICK HERE<\/a><\/br>/' -i /var/www/html/fail2ban.html`

**Result** - The entire HTML file now contains a list of links such as the following:

`<a href="http://10.30.20.40">CLICK HERE</a></br>`

---

**Problem** - Rather than "CLICK HERE" as the link text, I want to display the corresponding IP address instead. Example of desired result using example above:

`<a href="http://10.30.20.40">http://10.30.20.40</a></br>`

How can this final step be achieved using sed, awk, etc.?

---

Example input from file ***/var/www/html/fail2ban.html*** file containing the following three lines:

```
<a href="http://1.2.3.4">CLICK HERE</a></br>
<a href="http://5.6.7.8">CLICK HERE</a></br>
<a href="http://9.10.11.12">CLICK HERE</a></br>
```

Desired output:

```
<a href="http://1.2.3.4">http://1.2.3.4</a></br> 
<a href="http://5.6.7.8">http://5.6.7.8</a></br>
<a href="http://9.10.11.12">http://9.10.11.12</a></br>
```

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: I have added this, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a single `sed` command:

```
sed -e 's,^.*$,<a href="http://&">&</a></br>,' -i /var/www/html/fail2ban.html
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/SYsrPT):

```
s="10.23.34.23
56.67.22.12"
sed -e 's,^.*$,<a href="http://&">&</a></br>,' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
<a href="http://10.23.34.23">10.23.34.23</a></br>
<a href="http://56.67.22.12">56.67.22.12</a></br>
```

Notes:

- `^.*$` matches any line in full
- The `&` in the replacement refers to the full line text matches with `.*`
- The `,` char is used instead of `/` to avoid overescaping `/` chars in the regex and replacement patterns.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you Wiktor.